# If-else statement selecting both variables when a selection of one or the other is desired

Tags: r, loops, if-statement

I am working with time-series observation data in a dataframe called "all10". I want to create a new column of data that contains the observation 1hr. prior to a specified time, in this case 1 hour before hours 9 and 20 in months > 3 and <= 11 (ie. hours 8 and 19), and 1 hour before hours 10 and 21 in months <= 3 and > 11 (ie. hours 9 and 20). Eg.

```
Month   Hour Obs    Prior.1 
  10    0   1.76    0
  10    1   1.7     0
  10    2   1.55    0
  10    3   1.37    0
  10    4   1.22    0
  10    5   1.16    0
  10    6   1.16    0
  10    7   1.21    0
  10    8   1.19    1.19
  10    9   1.14    0
  10    10  1.12    0
  10    11  1.11    0
  10    12  1.17    0
  10    13  1.2     0
```

I've created an if-else loop that has worked before, however now when I run it, instead of selecting the proper hour depending on the month, it selects both hours like so:

```
 Month  Hour Obs    Prior.1 
  10    0   1.76    0
  10    1   1.7     0
  10    2   1.55    0
  10    3   1.37    0
  10    4   1.22    0
  10    5   1.16    0
  10    6   1.16    0
  10    7   1.21    0
  10    8   1.19    1.19
  10    9   1.14    1.14
  10    10  1.12    0
  10    11  1.11    0
  10    12  1.17    0
  10    13  1.2     0
```

And this is NOT what I want, I want the data for either Hours 8&19 OR Hours 9&20 depending on the month, never both at the same time.

This is my loop. It's worked before and I've combed through it a number of times and I'm really at a loss as to why this might be happening. 
Can anyone see anything wrong with the syntax of this statement?

Thank you for your time and energy.

```
prior=numeric(dim(all10)[1])
for(i in 1:dim(all10)[1]){
    if(all10$HourUTC[i]==8 || all10$HourUTC[i]==19){
        if(all10$Month[i] > 3 || all10$Month[i] <= 11){
            prior[i] = all10$Obs[i]
        }
        else{
            prior[i] = " "
        }
    }
    else if(all10$HourUTC[i]==9 || all10$HourUTC[i]==20){
        if(all10$Month[i] > 11 || all10$Month[i] <= 3){
            prior[i] = all10$Obs[i]
        }
        else{
            prior[i] = " "
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean that you wanted `1.19` for the `Prior.1` on `Hour=9`

Comment: Yes, because I want to select the observational data for one hour before Hour 9 and 20 for the specified months, so that would be the data for Hour 8 and Hour 19, and then when the months change also have the hours change. But right now its selecting both hours.

Comment: Might be easier to solve if you convert your month, Hours (and whatever other date-like information you have) to a single column with real date / time format.

Comment: But shouldn't it work with the code I have?